# Why can't all plastics form electrets?

Tags: electrostatics, material-science, dielectric

What property should a dielectric need to become an electret?

At first, I though polar dielectrics formed electrets, but non polar dielectrics like polypropylene also form electrets.

So what property do you need to become an electret?

Comment: Maybe they can, and just some are better than others. ;) Explaining *that* gets to the core of your question (IMHO).